# Why is pg_dump so slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-dump

Whenever I try to get a DB dump from AWS RDS I run the following:

```
pg_dump -h db.xxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com -U username -f dump_file.sql dbname
```

The resulting sql files are never more than 10mb in size but the command takes upwards of 10 minutes to process. Why is this happening and how can I make it faster? Internet connection speed is not a factor (20mbps+ speed)

Comment: What does CloudWatch tell you - any bottlenecks on the DB?

Comment: Where are you running the command? Are you running it on an Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC as the RDS database? That will provide the fastest connection speed. If you are doing it from your own computer, there will be network latency (which is more important than bandwidth). Try doing it from an EC2 instance to compare the speeds.